# Weird issue with Chrome inspect element

Tags: css, google-chrome

When I load my page, one of the images is higher than it is supposed to be. When I right click "Inspect element" anywhere on the page, the image shifts back to its normal position. What could cause this? In FF the image is in its correct position on page load. Here's what it looks like before and after inspect element: [image: http://community.glumbo.com/uploads/gallery/album_4/gallery_1_4_6556.png]

Comment: Is this something you wrote or just a standard amazon page? If the latter, what does what might be a Chrome bug have to do with programming? If the former, perhaps share some of your source so other can have a look at it (although it might still simply be a Chrome issue).

Comment: It's my site I was trying to debug. Here is the page http://www.glumbo.com/company-profiles/amazon.com

Comment: I can at least confirm it. Perhaps raise the issue with Chrome?

Comment: I am going to post in the chrome support forums. I wanted to see if it was anything on my code. Thanks

Comment: I'm using Chrome 13 on OSX and it is in the correct position. However, when I first load the page it is too far up, then it suddenly drops down to the correct position.

Comment: try removing the padding on the element that contain the image. The image seems to be pretty much the same height as the box that contains it, even a small padding to the container can make image "pop out".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the css below instead it should solve your problem.

```
#content{
    position: relative;
}
.page-company-profile .node .taxonomy_image_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 500px;
    top: 58px;
}
```