# Issue with misaligned field on Chrome that goes away on Inspect

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am having a similar problem to [Weird issue with Chrome inspect element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966081/weird-problem-with-chrome-inspect-element).  When I load the page the field is misaligned, appearing lower than it should.  However, if I click to inspect it, the 'Repeat" field misalignment goes away and the field becomes aligned with the 'To'. This only happens on Chrome (v15), it is not an issue with Firefox, Safari, IE.

Image: http://cl.ly/0P2b2W1C3H123e1z3p1q

```
<div class="date-time">
<ul class="select-index">
<li>
<div>   
<label style="width: 100%;">Schedule Type</label><br/>
<select class="large-select" id="schedule_time_scheme" name="schedule[time_scheme]">    
<option value="Custom" selected="selected">Custom</option>
<option value="Alternate_Weekends">Alternate weekends</option>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div id="repeat_schedule_div" style="margin: 20px 0px;">
<label>Repeat</label><br/>
<select class="large-select" name="from" id="repeat_select">
<option value="1">Every one Week</option>
</select>
</div>  
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.schedule-container .date-time { 
display: inline;
float: left;
width: 280px;
}

ul { 
display: block;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 1em;
margin-top: 1em;
padding-left: 40px;
}

ul.select-index { 
float: left;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
width: 100%;
}

ul.select-index li { 
float: left;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: relative;
width: auto;
}

.new #content .schedule-container .date-time label { 
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
float: left;
font-size: 13px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `<br />`-s try to always use CSS for alignment, e.g. set the margin-top for label - `label { display: block; margin-top: 15px }`

Also it would be helpful to see the markup and CSS to solve your issue

Comment: Thanks for responding, unfortunately that did not fix it... I added the CSS.  Really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi Zoltan, any chance you were able to look into this question?  I am totally stumped.  Thanks

Comment: Hey Luis, I've noticed that you don't have a closing `</select>` for the first list. Also try to delete the `margin: 20px 0px` from div `id =repeat_schedule_div` - if that helps and the problematic `div` jumps up, so you have to add that `20px` somewhere else(e.g. `padding-top: 20px` to parent `<li>`) http://jsfiddle.net/jG8DM/1/